# django left join with where clause subexpression

Tags: python, django, join, django-queryset, where-clause

I'm currently trying to find a way to do something with Django's (v1.10) ORM that I feel should be possible but I'm struggling to understand how to apply the documented methods to solve my problem.

**Edit:** So here's the sql that I've hacked together to return the data that I'd like from the `dbshell`, with a postgresql database now, after I realised that my original sqlite3 backed sql query was incorrect:

```
select 
    voting_bill.*,vv.vote 
from 
    voting_bill 
left join 
    (select 
        voting_votes.vote,voting_votes.bill_id 
    from 
        voting_bill 
    left join 
        voting_votes 
    on 
        voting_bill.id=voting_votes.bill_id 
    where 
        voting_votes.voter_id = (select id from auth_user where username='richard' or username is Null)
   ) 
as 
    vv 
on 
    voting_bill.id=vv.bill_id;
```

Here's the 'models.py' for my voting app:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Bill(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField()
    result = models.BooleanField()
    status = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Votes(models.Model):
    vote = models.NullBooleanField()
    bill = models.ForeignKey(Bill, related_name='bill',
                             on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
    voter = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{0} {1}'.format(self.bill, self.voter)
```

I can see that my sql works as I expect with the vote tacked onto the end, or a null if the user hasn't voted yet.

I was working to have the queryset in this format so that I can iterate over it in the template to produce a table and if the result is null I can instead provide a link which takes the user to another view.

I've read about select_related and prefetch_related, but as I said, I'm struggling to work out how I translate this to how I can do this in SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope I correctly understood your problem. Try this:

```
votes = Votes.objects.filter(voter__username='django').select_related('bill')
```

You can use this. But I think you do not need `select_related` in this case.

```
bills_for_user = Bill.objects.filter(votes__voter__username='django').select_related('votes').distinct()
```

Now you can iterate your bills_for_user

```
for bill in bills_for_user:
    bill_name = bill.name
    bill_description = bill.description
    bill_result = bill.result
    bill_status = bill.status

    # and there are several variants what you can with votes
    bill_votes = bill.votes_set.all()  # will return you all votes for this bill
    bill_first_vote1 = bill.votes_set.first() # will return first element in this query or None if its empty
    bill_first_vote2 = bill.votes_set.all()[0] # will return first element in this query or Error if its empty
    bill_last_vote = bill.votes_set.last()[0] # will return last element in this query or None if its empty
    # you can also filter it for example by voting
    bill_positive_votes = bill.votes_set.filter(vote=True) # will return you all votes for this bill with 'vote' = True
    bill_negative_votes = bill.votes_set.filter(vote=False) # will return you all votes for this bill with 'vote' = False
    bill_neutral_votes = bill.votes_set.filter(vote=None) # will return you all votes for this bill with 'vote' = None
```

Comment: Hmm, I think that won't do what I want if I read it correctly.

I want to return all the bills, but I want to keep the filter on the Votes as you have done there.

I kind of want something like:

    bills_for_user = Bills.objects.select_related('votes').filter(votes__voter=request.user)

Comment: Edited. Now you can iterate over bills query set

Comment: With `bills = Bill.objects.filter(
        votes__voter__id=request.user.id).select_related('votes').distinct()` `Cannot resolve keyword 'votes' into field. Choices are: bill, description, id, name, result, status`

Comment: I don't seem to be able to edit comments for some reason, but there's an error message after the code.

Basically it doesn't seem to like votes somewhere, either in the select related or in the filter.  I've been playing around, but most of the time I can't get select related to work with the Bill model, because it is the reverse of the FK?  The FK is on the Votes model

Comment: Edited. Missed 'related_name` in your Votes model. Its a bit disorienting, because commonly `related_name` uses the same name as model name to make it more human readable in reverse relations, but in you case you will have instance of `Bill` with `bill` attribute, which really `Votes` set.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in responding.  I removed the confusing related_name as I too was finding that this complicated things.

    bill = models.ForeignKey(Bill, on_delete=models.CASCADE,)

with the following in my view:

    bills = Bill.objects.filter(
        votes__voter__id=request.user.id
    ).select_related('bill').distinct()

I get the following error message:

    Invalid field name(s) given in select_related: 'bill'. Choices are: (none)

Comment: Thats because you removed this `related name`. Ok I've edited request.

Comment: Ah okay that makes sense.  I actually got something similar to you in the end I think.  I then realised that my initial query was incorrect and wasn't returning what I wanted.

`    bills = Bill.objects.all()
    for bill in bills:
        vote = Votes.objects.get(bill=bill.id).filter(voter__id=request.user.id)
        if vote:
            v = vote.get(bill=bill.id)
            bill.votes_set.add(v)`

Template code:
`{% for bill in bills %}
<tr>
    {% for votes in bill.votes_set.all %}
        <td>{{ votes.vote }}</td>
    {% endfor %}
</tr>
{% endfor %}`

Comment: Looks like your code made similar things, but I've used only one request to DataBase and have all data instead of multiple requests in loop. Also it is bad practice to use .get() without wrapping it in `try - except`. If I've answered your question I'll appreciate if you mark it as solved and vote up.